# Running a angular build, but I get an error, in the template of component HeaderComponent

Tags: html, node.js, angular

Im currently trying to run my project with ng serve, but I get an error at this location. This is supposed to be my logic where once successfully login. It would go to the link.

error TS2341: Property 'loginService' is private and only accessible within class 'HeaderComponent'.

```
    <nav class ="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div><a href="https://www.javainuse.com" class="navbar-brand">JavaInUse</a></div>
    
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
       
      <!-- <li><a *ngIf="loginService.isUserLoggedIn()" routerLink="/" class="nav-link">View Employees</a></li>
      <li><a *ngIf="loginService.isUserLoggedIn()" routerLink="/addemployee" class="nav-link">Add New Employee</a></li> -->
      <li><a *ngIf="!loginService.isUserLoggedIn()" routerLink="/login" class="nav-link">Login</a></li>
      <!--<li><a *ngIf="loginService.isUserLoggedIn()" routerLink="/logout" class="nav-link">LogOut</a></li> -->
    
    </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

I have made my loginService public, I'm not sure where I went wrong with this.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  username = 'javainuse'
  password = ''
  invalidLogin = false

  constructor(public router: Router,
    public loginservice: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

Comment: Can you please share the error?

Comment: I just add the error code

Comment: @KKNg, your variable is `loginservice`  (all in lower case) you're using in .html `loginService` (in camel case) -the "S" in uppercase-